I need to list api calls in ionic app form source code, has anyone done this before?
I have implemented some changes in the backend part of the application, some ionic apps perform various api calls with different payloads to this application. We don't have any document containing list of api calls done by ionic apps.
Is there any plugin or tool which can scan the ionic code base or repository and list all the api calls ? If not what is the next best thing for me to do ? All inputs are welcome
I tried using GPT, one possible way is to scan http logs but that is not what I am looking for, I need to find out all api calls, high chance of missing less used apis if I take the logging route.

Open your code in any editor and Search for API calls. Search for baseUrl variable and you will get all your calls.

Thank You, I have doubt tho are there many ways to create api's in ionic or baseurl is the only way. I just wanna make sure I get all the calls.
